# SAS Proc Groovy - Apache PDFBox library is not able to read resource from pdfbox.jar file

Tags: java, sas, pdfbox, pdftotext

Goal: Read PDF file and convert it into text format.

I am using SAS "Proc Groovy" and "Java Apache PDFBox Library" for this. But the code is giving Error since Apache PDFBox version has been changed from 2.0.21 to 2.0.22. Please suggest what changes has to be done to this code, to work it again.

SAS Proc Groovy enables to run Java code. So we are using a Java PDF Library (Apache PDFBox) into SAS Proc Groovy for converting PDF into text format.

Code:

```
filename overview "&temp/overview.pdf";
filename ov_text  "&temp/overview.txt";

* download a pdf document;
proc http           
url="https://cdn.nar.realtor/sites/default/files/documents/ehs-11-2020-overview-2020-12-22.pdf"       
method="get"        
proxyhost="&proxy_host."        
proxyport=&port         
out=overview;     
run;

* download the Apache PDFBox library (a .jar file); 
filename jar '&temp/pdfbox.jar';

%if %sysfunc(FEXIST(jar)) ne 1 %then %do;
proc http
url='https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?filename=pdfbox/2.0.22/pdfbox-app-2.0.22.jar&action=download'
proxyhost="&proxy_host."        
proxyport=&port
out=jar;
run;
%end;

* Use GROOVY to read the PDF, strip out the text and position, and write that
* parse to a text file which SAS can read;

proc groovy classpath="&temp.jar"; 
  submit 
    "%sysfunc(pathname(overview))"  /* the input, a pdf file */
    "%sysfunc(pathname(ov_text))"   /* the output, a text file */
  ;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.TextPosition;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class GetLinesFromPDF extends PDFTextStripper {
    
    static List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    public GetLinesFromPDF() throws IOException {
    }
    /**
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing the document.
     */
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        String inPdf = args[0];
        String outTxt = args[1];

        try {
            document = PDDocument.load( new File(inPdf) );

            PDFTextStripper stripper = new GetLinesFromPDF();

            stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
            stripper.setStartPage( 0 );
            stripper.setEndPage( document.getNumberOfPages() );

            Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
            stripper.writeText(document, dummy);
            
            out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outTxt));

            // print lines to text file
            for(String line:lines){
              out.println(line); 
            }
        }
        finally {
            if( document != null ) {
                document.close();
            }
            if( out != null ) {
                out.close();
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Override the default functionality of PDFTextStripper.writeString()
     */
    @Override
    protected void writeString(String str, List<TextPosition> textPositions) throws IOException {
        String places = "";

        for(TextPosition tp:textPositions){
          places += "(" + tp.getX() + "," + tp.getY() + ") ";
        }

        lines.add(str + " found @ " + places);
    }
}

  endsubmit;
quit;

* preview the stripped text that was saved;

data _null_;
  infile ov_text;
  input;
  putlog _infile_;
run;
```

Part of Error Message after running the above code:

```
    ERROR: The SUBMIT command failed.
    groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Failed to create Script instance for class: class GetLinesFromPDF. Reason: 
    java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
         at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.createScript(InvokerHelper.java:475)
         at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:689)
         at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:725)
         at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:716)
    Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error reading zip file
         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
         at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(ZipFile.java:60)
         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(ZipFile.java:734)
         at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(ZipFile.java:434)
         at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:158)
         at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
         at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
         at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
         at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
         at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
         at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
         at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.encoding.GlyphList.loadList(GlyphList.java:147)
         at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.encoding.GlyphList.<init>(GlyphList.java:137)
         at org.apache.pdfbox.text.LegacyPDFStreamEngine.<init>(LegacyPDFStreamEngine.java:120)
         at org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper.<init>(PDFTextStripper.java:214)
```

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with the jar download itself. Make sure that the checksum is correct. If yes, then open the .jar file with a tool like 7zip and look for "/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/glyphlist/additional.txt".

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I am not able to open the .jar file and neither my org has 7zip tool in their software center. But I can see the .jar file downloaded in the out file location with 9,687 KB.

Comment: The size is 9918496 and the SHA512 is `24077504894b711177330bd550d8cf0263640b17e54020f9b10cf0e2a9b5b80c8d81dd094b214b216fddc1fd3ee23258d46cc0926f3891907a9e9d0fc77a10df`. If you can't use 7zip then rename the file to .zip and try to open it.

Comment: Also try to run from the command line, that would be `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.22.jar ExtractText yourfile.txt`.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I renamed the file to .zip and I could open "/org/apache/pdfbox/resources/glyphlist/additional.txt". But how to resolve the error now?

Comment: I don't know... if the file has 153 lines and ends with "#END" then it is OK. Consider deleting and updating your java installation. Did you verify the hast, and also tried running from the command line?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes the file has 153 lines and ends with "#END". To delete and update Java I need to raise a ticket and it might take some days. Yes I ran from the command line, below is the result of it: `Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1103)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:2577)
        at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:2560)
……`

Comment: I tried deleting and reinstalling Java. Now the error message is like: `ERROR: The SUBMIT command failed.
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script8.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument
 @ line 2, column 2.
    import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;`

Comment: @Richard Can you please help me in debugging this ? The code was working fine, but suddenly stopped working since the new version of Apache PDFBox library. Do I have to change anything in my code ?

Comment: "unable to resolve class" would mean the PDFBox jar file is missing now.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr But the PDFBox jar file is present and even I renamed the file to .zip and checked if it has additional.txt with 153 lines and ending with "#153".

Comment: You should rename it back to .jar. And the file should end with "#END" not "#153".

Comment: @anilkumar Your exact code, with trivial modifications for my environment, worked for me.  Your issue is either your Java installation or your system path.  If you're running this on a server, you may want to contact your SAS administrator for help.

Comment: @Joe Will check with my SAS Admin. Thanks.